# reading data from json inside test block causing failure with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am executing the below code that converts data from excel to json file and login to application and picks the data from json file.

```
describe('Validate login feature', function() {
    before(() => {
        cy.task('readXLSX', {"./cypress/fixtures/data1/studDetails.xlsx", "students"});
    }

    it('Login Test', function() {
      cy.visit('http://localhost:8081/login/')
    }
});
```

'readXLSX' function written in plugins/index.js.
When I execute the above code, json file generated as expected. No issues till here.

I have manually deleted the 'data2' folder that contains the json file and again re-executed the code by including one more line in the test to work with the data inside the json file.

```
it('Login Test', function() {
   cy.visit('http://localhost:8081/login/');
   const studList = require('../../fixtures/data2/studDetails.json');
}
```

This time, it shows the below error in results:

Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/fixtures/data2/studDetails.json
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Renet\Demo\RN2022\cypress\fixtures\data2\studDetails.json'

If I haven't removed the 'data2' folder containing the json file and executed with the additional line included in the test, then there are no issues. The issues occurs when there is no 'data2' folder with json file and if I included the below statement in the test.

```
 const studList = require('../../fixtures/data2/studDetails.json');
```

Could someone please help me to understand what is causing the failure?

Comment: You are delete the folder `data2` and the `studDetails.json` along with it, then you are trying to access the nonexistent `studDetails.json` file which would be in the nonexistent `data2` folder. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Let me explain. Every time, when this code is executed then the 'data2' folder gets created and the data from excel in 'data1' folder gets converted to json file in 'data2' folder. So, we can delete the 'data2' folder as many time we want. It shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The issue here is, when the below line is included then the 'data2' folder is not created. If we exclude this line, then the 'data2' folder is created and excel file converted to json file and stored in 'data2' folder.

Comment: const studList = require('../../fixtures/data2/studDetails.json');

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. It seems like a async with sync code mix. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So your `readXLSX` task generates the json file in `data2` folder. Cypress queues up all cypress commands and then executes them. Any non Cypress commands will be executed immediately.

So in your case, the `const studList = require('../../fixtures/data2/studDetails.json');` is execute before your `readXLSX` task is executed, thus you get your failure. You should move your `before()` code outside of your `describe()` block for it to run first before the tests. So your code will look like this:

```
before(() => { // this will execute before the describe block
    cy.task('readXLSX', {"./cypress/fixtures/data1/studDetails.xlsx", "students"});
}
describe('Validate login feature', function() {
    it('Login Test', function() {
      const studList = require('../../fixtures/data2/studDetails.json');
      cy.visit('http://localhost:8081/login/')
      // rest of your code
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I just brought out the before() code outside describe() block as you suggested. Then, I got the below error during run: Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/integration/demo/test1.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../fixtures/JSONData/studDetails.json' in 'E:\Renet\Demo\RN2022\cypress\integration\demo'

Comment: Hmm, is this test withing the `before()` and `describe()` blocks the only code in this test file?

Comment: I have exactly copied the code you pasted above and executed. Then, got the error: Error: Webpack Compilation Error ./cypress/integration/demo/test1.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../fixtures/JSONData/studDetails.json' in 'E:\Renet\Demo\RN2022\cypress\integration\demo'

Comment: I believe this is the line creating the problem here: const studList = require('../../fixtures/data2/studDetails.json');

Comment: Is it possible to have your `readXLSX` task return the `const studList = require('../../fixtures/data2/studDetails.json');`?